# How to store blob in another location, ie. /uploads/audio/currenttime.wav?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, audio, blob

How to store audio blob with name in another location, ie. /uploads/audio/currenttime.wav

```
function saveRecording() {
    rec.stop();
    rec.exportWAV(createDownloadLink);
}

function createDownloadLink(blob) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    //add controls to the <audio> element
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    //link the a element to the blob
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'audio-' + Date.now() + '.wav';
    link.innerHTML = link.download;
    //add the new audio and a elements to the li element
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(link);
    //add the li element to the ordered list
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: what do you mean? Only the user gets to choose where a file is saved.

Comment: How to store blob in a directory with name